# Vocal Effects on Real Time Audio

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, audio-processing, audioeffect

I'm working on a app like Smule, I have tried Tarsosdsp to apply echo effect on vocals while recording. Now i'm trying to apply reverb effect while recording audio. Please guide me how smule app is processing audio effects.is there any native way to do that or i have to go with some other way?

Comment: Please find better tags for your question. Posting this to people who are expert in Java, xml or kotlin is very unlikely to find the people who can actually help.

Comment: This is a brand new singing plataform project which is beggining - LiveJam. github.com/richardaum/livejam Take a look and consider support us - we are looking expert contributors and you could be one of us.